# HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized field using Spring boot and Android

Tags: java, json, reactjs, spring, spring-boot

I'm developing and web application which communicates with my Server. This communication is done thru Spring framework and react js. I'm sending an request for my server to read json but i got this error

error react console :

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 400

error spring boot :

> 2020-08-10 11:54:34.550  WARN 22020 --- [nio-8080-exec-3]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:
> I/O error while reading input message; nested exception is
> java.io.IOException: Stream closed]

image json :

[image]

code react js :

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      rfp: false,
      rfx: false,
      rfp_x: false,
      allclassification: false,
  
       eu : false,
      americas: false,
      aae: false,
      ger: false,
      eu2: false,
      latam : false,
      empty: false,
      allregion: false,
    }
    
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const FilterClassification = {
      // classification
      rfx: this.state.rfx,
      rfp: this.state.rfp,
      rfp_x: this.state.rfp_x,
      allclassification: this.state.allclassification
    };
    const FilterRegion = {
      //Region
     eu : this.state.eu,
    americas  : this.state.americas,
    aae : this.state.aae,
    ger: this.state.ger,
    eu2 : this.state.eu2,
    latam : this.state.latam,
    empty : this.state.empty,
    allregion : this.state.allregion,
    }





console.log(FilterClassification);
    console.log(FilterRegion);
    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/MenuFiltre/filtreregioncloser",FilterClassification , FilterRegion )
  }
```

Code java  spring boot :

```
    @PostMapping("/filtreregioncloser")
    public Iterable<Closerfprfx>gettab1(@RequestBody  FilterClassification FilterClassification  , @RequestBody  FilterRegion FilterRegion) 
    {
    boolean rfx = FilterClassification.isRfx();
            String ChaineRfx = "";
            if(rfx==true)
            {
                ChaineRfx="rfx";
            }else
            {
                ChaineRfx="xxxx";
            }
            boolean rfp =FilterClassification.isRfp() ;
            String ChaineRfp = "";
            if(rfp == true)
            {
                ChaineRfp="rfp";
            }else
            {
                ChaineRfp="xxxx";
            }
            boolean rfp_x= FilterClassification.isRfp_x();
            String ChaineRfp_x = "";
            if(rfp_x==true)
            {
                ChaineRfp_x="rfp_x";
            }else
            {
                ChaineRfp_x="xxxx";
            }
            boolean allclassification = FilterClassification.isAllclassification() ;
            
            
               boolean eu = FilterRegion.isEu();
               String ChaineEu= "";
               if(eu==true)
               {
                   ChaineEu="eu";
               }else
               {
                   ChaineEu="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  americas = FilterRegion.isAmericas();
               String ChaineAmericas = "";
               if(americas==true)
               {
                   ChaineAmericas="americas";
               }
               else {
                   ChaineAmericas="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  aae = FilterRegion.isAae();
               String ChaineAae = "";
               if(aae==true)
               {
                   ChaineAae="aae";
               }else {
                   ChaineAae="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  ger = FilterRegion.isGer();
               String ChaineGer="";
               if(ger==true)
               {
                   ChaineGer="ger";
                   
               }else
               {
                   ChaineGer="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  eu2 = FilterRegion.isEu2();
               String ChaineEu2="";
               if(eu2=true)
               {
                   ChaineEu2="eu2";
               }else {
                   ChaineEu2="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  latam = FilterRegion.isLatam() ;
               String ChaineLatam = "";
               if(latam=true)
               {
                   ChaineLatam="latam";
                   }else {
                   ChaineLatam="xxxx";
               }
               boolean  empty = FilterRegion.isEmpty();
               String ChaineEmpty="";
               if(empty=true)
               {
                   ChaineEmpty="empty";
               }else {
                   ChaineEmpty="xxxx";
               }
                boolean  allregion = FilterRegion.isAllregion();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above - you can't have 2 or more @RequestBody. I recommend creating a wrapper class that will hold these parameters from these 2 classes of yours. Also get rid of this 'logic' from your controller layer... and get rid of these ifs... consider using pattern matching from vavr library since strategy pattern seems to be overkill there

Answer (score 1):

> @RequestBody annotated parameter is expected to hold the entire body
> of the request and bind to one object

I think u can't have more than one RequestBody in your parameters